# Overseer of the Damned board wipe

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens with [Overseer of the Damned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Overseer%20of%20the%20Damned) in the case of a board wipe? I know that all the creatures die at the same time, so do I still get zombies or is that ability mulled by the fact that Overseer is now gone?

Comment: In that example the creature causing the trigger was not killed.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the wrong link, it should be http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18269/what-happens-when-a-creature-with-whenever-a-creature-dies-dies-simultaneously?rq=1

Comment: @Diego It is indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your opponent had two copies of [Grizzly Bear](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grizzly%20Bear) it would result in all three creatures being destroyed and afterwards you placing two 2/2 Black Zombie creature tokens into play tapped.

[Overseer of the Damned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Overseer%20of%20the%20Damned) has a triggered ability which is placed onto the stack the next time a player would get priority. Put more succinctly, the ability doesn't go onto the stack until after the board wipe has finished resolving.