# Jar of Eyeballs vs mass destruction

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A [Pernicious Deed](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pernicious%20Deed) is destroying my token army along with my counterless [Jar of Eyeballs](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jar%20of%20Eyeballs). Can I use the jar's activated ability before it goes to the graveyard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really - X would be zero.

If you let Pernicious Deed's ability resolve, it destroys everything simultaneously. Even if it didn't, there's no chance to cast other spells or activate other abilities while something is resolving. The Jar's first ability does still trigger and try to put counters on it, but again, that doesn't resolve until after the Deed's ability does, so by the time it resolves, the Jar is also already in the graveyard. Its ability tries to put counters on it, but it's not there, so nothing happens.

So by the time you get a chance to do anything, your Jar is already gone. Your last chance to use it is before the Deed's ability resolves, but at that point your Jar has no eyeballs, so activating the ability won't do anything useful. You can still do it, but I don't think X=0 is what you were hoping for.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18270/2668), won't the jar leave the battlefield with counters as its triggers resolved while the deed resolved?

Comment: No. First off, like I said, everything gets destroyed simultaneously. And additionally, while Jar does technically trigger like I said, those triggers have to go on the stack. They don't *resolve* until the Deed's ability is done resolving, and at that point there's nowhere to put the counters so like I said, nothing actually happens.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman In the answer you linked, the permanent in question _already had counters on it_. In this case, the triggered ability that adds counters only triggers as the recipient is entering the graveyard. By the time those abilities resolve, the recipient is in the wrong zone and can't receive counters.