# Does Harvester of Souls trigger its own death trigger when it dies

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Specifically, does a player draw a card when [Harvester of Souls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHarvester%20of%20Souls%5d) dies?

Comment: For the abilities that don't say "*another* creature" see http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18269/409

Answer (score 4):

**No, Harvester of Souls does not trigger its own death trigger**

Read the card carefully, it says

> Whenever **another** nontoken creature dies, you may draw a card.

It specifically doesn't count itself. For other creatures, it depends on the exact wording of that card and cannot be stated generally.

Comment: Oh duh... but I'm curious now. If "another" was changed to "any" would a player still draw a card?

Comment: Yes, of course. Although the wording would be "whenever a nontoken creatures dies..."

Comment: Why of course? Is it just a no brainer or some kind of rule? If a triggering event occurs at the same time the trigger disappears from the battle field, how can a trigger be triggered? Mind = blown

Comment: They said "of course" because it's a very very common thing

Comment: **If a triggering event occurs at the same time the trigger disappears from the battle field, how can a trigger be triggered?**

Comment: @the_prole Creatures see themselves enter or leave the battlefield (as well as anything else that comes and goes at the same time). This is necessary for many simple effects to work. For example, Filigree Familiar. If it didn't see itself enter, its first ability wouldn't work. If it didn't see itself leave, its second wouldn't. Because they want simple "when this dies, do X" effects to work, they make the rules work for this.