# Necroskitter and clone/ board wipe interaction

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I had [Necroskitter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNecroskitter%5d) out and my opponent has [Clone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%5d) which cloned some 3/3 monster. I play [Puncture Blast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPuncture%20Blast%5d) to kill it. I believe that I get [Clone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%5d) card because of the following steps

1. Cast puncture bolt
2. Target Clone creature
3. Opponent has no response so there for it dies
4. Because it has -1/-1 counter when it was sent to the graveyard it triggers my Necroskitter
5. I get to put Clone into my battlefield

I believe I am right but my friend says that [Clone][2] comes back as 0/0 as therefore dies. Who is right?

Comment: You would be better off separating this into two questions.  Stack Exchange encourages each question to have it's own individual post.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that but I understand the reasoning for it. I'll do my best to remember that for future questions on all boards.

Comment: A lot of forums encourage question collation in order to save space, but Stack Exchange's primary priority is to provide a searchable database of answers, which is why the "one question per post" rule is preferred.

Comment: So would it be best to do that for this question right now?

Comment: Edit out the second question, and then repost it as a new question. Or better yet, don't repost it at all, because it would just get closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18269/what-happens-when-a-creature-with-whenever-a-creature-dies-dies-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe I am right but my friend says that Clone comes back as 0/0 as therefore dies. Who is right?

## You are correct.

Clone's ability reads

> You may have Clone enter the battlefield as a copy of any creature on the battlefield.

This ability applies any time Clone enters the battlefield.  The person who controls Clone (in this case you) gets to choose a creature to copy as it enters the battlefield.  It will not die.

Comment: More precisely, the ability applies any time Clone *would* enter the battlefield. Assuming that the ability is used and a valid option exists, "Clone" never enters the battlefield, the copy does instead.